# Process Builder not getting triggered on update to field via time dependent action

Tags: process-builder, time-dependent-workflow

I have a Process Builder process that 'watches' updates to 3 fields on the Case object, and on updates to any of these 3 fields, does stuff (sends a message to a AWS SQS Q).

When any of those 3 fields of interest are updated manually, the process is triggered and all is well.

However, in the case where those fields are updated via a Workflow rule (Time based workflow action), the process does not get triggered.

Now I have read that updates to formula fields do not trigger Process Builder processes, but does a similar constraint apply to fields updated via Time based workflow actions as well?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to check the checkbox which say `reevaluate wf on field update` on WF field update. then your process builder work without any issue.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the prompt reply, Tushar! That worked for me.